# How to ExecStartPre another systemd unit?

Tags: systemd

I have an application.

I want to run two system units before each time it starts.

The first unit checks for application updates.

The second unit installs any updates is available.

```
[Unit]
Description=worker application
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/worker/workerapp
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStartPre=appupdate_fetch.service
ExecStartPre=appupdate_install.service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/worker/workerapp/bundle.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The above unit file results in `Exec format error`

```
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-09-15 22:34:53 UTC; 7min ago
 Main PID: 645 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
```

Is there a way to specify a service in ExecStartPre?

Comment: Calling `systemctl` from within another service is prone to dead locks.

Comment: Sorry I should have said that the ExecStartPre units are oneshot.

Comment: why use separate services just call the commands directly

Comment: @CameronNemo because each unit has an override.conf file that sets environment variables.

Comment: Don't use anything other than the distro's package manager for application updates. Your distro is very likely to have some software to automatically install updates - and that usually means restarting your systemd unit after the update as well. Everything else is more prone to fail and definitely harder to develop / set up

Answer (score 1):

You'd want you application to have:

```
[Unit]
After=appupdate_install.service
```

And you'd want appupdate_install.service to have:

```
[Unit]
After=appupdate_fetch.service
```

You can set these as overrides too. These add to the `After` list rather than replacing it.